# input/output for very very basic JS

Tags: javascript

First program in JS.  I don't understand why I can see neither output of the conditional in the second script.  Thank you, and pre-emptive apologies for not knowing what it is I'm asking for help with.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function init() {
        var num = window.prompt("Enter a number");
        num_span = document.getElementById("entered_num");
        num_span.innerHTML = num;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="init()">
    
    <h1>We math!</h1>
    
    Your number is
    <p id ="here">MEMEME</p>
    perfect!
    
    <script>
    function isPerfect(n){
        var snowball = 1;
        var half_n = n >> 1;
        for (var k = 2; k <= half_n; k++){
            if (n % k == 0) {
                snowball += k;
            }
        }
        return (snowball == n);  
    }
    
    if (!isPerfect(num)) {
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "not";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "definitely";
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: The error messages should be a clue...`num` is wrapped in a function. It is not accessible from outside of that function. This is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  OP is asking a valid question that pertains to order of execution of their code.  Its a "noob" question, but a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for if(!isPerfect(num)) is only executed once, and that is when the page is being loaded.  You want the logic to execute AFTER the number has been provided by the user.  So you will need to change the init method as such:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function init() {
      var num = window.prompt("Enter a number");
      if (!isPerfect(num)) {
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "not";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "definitely";
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="init()">
    
    <h1>We math!</h1>
    
    Your number is
    <p id ="here">MEMEME</p>
    perfect!
    
    <script>
    function isPerfect(n){
        var snowball = 1;
        var half_n = n >> 1;
        for (var k = 2; k <= half_n; k++){
            if (n % k == 0) {
                snowball += k;
            }
        }
        return (snowball == n);  
    }
    
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: @Liam fair.  I did not remove the snippet that I moved into init().  updated now.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
function init() {
    var num = window.prompt("Enter a number");
    if (!isPerfect(num)) {
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = document.getElementById("here").innerHTML +  " not";
} else {
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = document.getElementById("here").innerHTML + " definitely";
}
}
function isPerfect(n){
    var snowball = 1;
    var half_n = n >> 1;
    for (var k = 2; k <= half_n; k++){
        if (n % k == 0) {
            snowball += k;
        }
    }
    return (snowball == n);  
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">

<h1>We math!</h1>

Your number is
<p id ="here"></p>
perfect!
```

You wanted something like this ?

Comment: I'm still not seeing either of the two outcomes to the conditional.  (I've opened in "incognito," so as not to be loading an older version, if that matters at all, too).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
      function init() {
          var num = prompt("Enter a number");
          if (num != null) {
              document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = num ;
          }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
      <h1>We math!</h1>
      Your number is
      <p id ="here">MEMEME</p>
      perfect!
    </body>
</html>
```